# How to convert a function of differential equations to an anonymous function

Tags: matlab, anonymous-function, ode

I am trying to convert a function of differential equations to an anonymous function, but I am struggling with it. The reason I need to do this is because there are constants which are time dependent with the variables, and the interp1 function was not working well, so I have defined the constants as anonymous functions which would be run with the same t variable as the differential equations, and it doesn't seem like an anonymous function can passed to the main function as it has always resulted in an unrecognized variable/function error. I was able to have one differential equation solved when it was run as an anonymous function as well (this way the anonymous function constant could be run with it as well).

```
function dC = mechanism(t, C)
% Variables
        CNiII   = C(1);
        CNiIISH = C(2);
        CNiISH  = C(3);
        CNiIIIH = C(4);
        CNiIIH  = C(5);
        Ce      = C(6);
        CH      = C(7);
        CH2     = C(8);

     % Rate Laws
        dNiISH  = kred*CNiIISH - kox*CNiISH - k1*CNiISH;
        dNiII   = -ka*CNiII*CH + kb*CNiIISH + k2*CNiIIH*CH;
        de      = -kred*(CNiIISH + CNiIIIH) + kox*(CNiISH + CNiIIH);
        dNiIIIH = k1*CNiISH - kred*CNiIIIH + kox*CNiIIH;
        dNiIIH  = kred*CNiIIIH - kox*CNiIIH - k2*CNiIIH*CH;
        dNiIISH = -kb*CNiIISH + ka*CNiII*CH - kred*CNiIISH + kox*CNiISH;
        dH      = -k2*CNiIIH*CH; - ka*CNiII*CH + kb*CNiIISH;
        dH2     = k2*CNiIIH*CH;

     % Assign Output Variables
        dC(1,:) = dNiII;
        dC(2,:) = dNiIISH;
        dC(3,:) = dNiISH;
        dC(4,:) = dNiIIIH;
        dC(5,:) = dNiIIH;
        dC(6,:) = de;
        dC(7,:) = dH;
        dC(8,:) = dH2;
end
```

I am stumped as to how to put all of these into one anonymous function because all 8 different variables would have to be their own parameter, but they all need to be solved together. I tried this

```
Enfcn = @(t) Ei + v * t;
kredfcn = @(t) k0 .* exp(((-a * F)/(R * T)) * (Enfcn(t) - Eo));
koxfcn  = @(t) k0 .* exp((((1-a) * F)/(R * T)) * (Enfcn(t) - Eo));

myODE = {@(t, CNiII, CNiIISH, CNiISH, CNiIIIH, CNiIIH, CH) kred(t)*CNiIISH - kox(t)*CNiISH - k1*CNiISH;
         @(t, CNiII, CNiIISH, CNiISH, CNiIIIH, CNiIIH, CH) -ka*CNiII*CH + kb*CNiIISH + k2*CNiIIH*CH;
         @(t, CNiII, CNiIISH, CNiISH, CNiIIIH, CNiIIH, CH) -kred(t)*(CNiIISH + CNiIIIH) + kox(t)*(CNiISH + CNiIIH);
         @(t, CNiII, CNiIISH, CNiISH, CNiIIIH, CNiIIH, CH) k1*CNiISH - kred(t)*CNiIIIH + kox(t)*CNiIIH;
         @(t, CNiII, CNiIISH, CNiISH, CNiIIIH, CNiIIH, CH) kred(t)*CNiIIIH - kox(t)*CNiIIH - k2*CNiIIH*CH;
         @(t, CNiII, CNiIISH, CNiISH, CNiIIIH, CNiIIH, CH) -kb*CNiIISH + ka*CNiII*CH - kred(t)*CNiIISH + kox(t)*CNiISH;
         @(t, CNiII, CNiIISH, CNiISH, CNiIIIH, CNiIIH, CH) -k2*CNiIIH*CH - ka*CNiII*CH + kb*CNiIISH;
         @(t, CNiII, CNiIISH, CNiISH, CNiIIIH, CNiIIH, CH) k2*CNiIIH*CH;}

IC = [0.01, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1e6, 0];

[A, B] = ode15s(myODE, tspan, IC);
```

But I got the error: Error using exist
The first input to exist must be a string scalar or
character vector.

Error in odearguments (line 59)
if (exist(ode)==2)

Comment: Please copy-paste the full error message, it’s more useful to us than the vague error description. Also, it is unclear why you need an anonymous function, when you have a perfectly working function already. There is no advantage to the function being anonymous (== without a name).

Comment: `dC(1,:)` refers to a matrix that has not been created. Moreover, you are returning a matrix instead of a vector.

Comment: @Tarik: it is legal in MATLAB to write into an array that doesn’t exist, it is created. `dC` becomes an 8x1 matrix, which is a vector in MATLAB. There exists no true 1D data structure in MATLAB, everything has 2 or more dimensions.

Comment: Please read [mcve]. You can do `myODE = @(t,c1,c2) [k(t)*c1; -ka(t)*c2]` intead of making a cell array of anonymous functions.

Comment: You should be able to use the first approach you tried, define the coefficients functions as anonymous functions and use them in the `mechanism` function. You would have to give the code for that approach and the exact error message. Perhaps try for the simpler equation/shorter system `y''(t)+q(t)*y(t)=0` with `q = @(t) sin(t)` as external function, use something like `y(0)=1, y'(0)=0` as initial condition.

Comment: The easy way of making your first function an anonymous function is this: `myODE=@(t,C) mechanism(t, C)`. You don't need to define in one line, you can use an existing function to make an anonymous function! Another example: `mysin=@(x)sin(x)` is a valid way of making a sin function with another name.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I'm sorry if I was not clear... The constants kox and kred are time dependent constants for which interp1 did not produce the correct results for. My idea to fix this was to have these constants, kox and kred, be anonymous functions with the same t variable as the function dC so that they would be run with the same time, however, I cannot use the anonymous function in the main function definition (I get the error unknown variable or function). As for the complete error message, I have put it in the main text.

Comment: @AnderBiguri Thank you for the helpful comments! Do you have examples of what you say so that I can have a better idea of how to execute it? Also, if I defined the function as an anonymous function by myODE = @(t, C).... how would I pass the kox/kred to it?

Comment: The line of code I gave you is not only "one example" but the code you need... have you.... read my comment? tried it? Just replace your `myODE` definition  for mine.

Comment: @Ander: `myODE=@(t,C) mechanism(t, C)` is less efficient than `myODE=@mechanism`, I think, but accomplish the same thing.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I though that would be resolved by the interpreter, and have no effect, but in any case, the first seems a bit more clear in purpose, for OP to understand, I think.

Comment: @AnderBiguri yes, sorry, I intended to mention another comment, but you can only mention one person... At any rate, I did try it, but I still run into the problem that the variable kred is unrecognized in the function dC definition because I have it as an anonymous function, which I need...

Comment: The docs of ode45 have examples of how to solve the issues you are having. Please, go trhough them slowly. ;)